# json Parsing using url

Tags: android, json, parsing, url

I'm trying to parse json using an url. I'm able to achive it by using Temporary url but when I use my main host url, json returns html values?

Temporary URL

```
(http://md-plesk-web9.webhostbox.net:8880/sitepreview/http/glossymob.asia/Webservice.asmx/SpecificCategory?category=real%20estate&location=Madurai)
```

My Code

```
// url to make request
private static String url = "http://md-plesk-web9.webhostbox.net:8880/sitepreview/http/glossymob.asia/Webservice.asmx/SpecificCategory?category=hotel&location=Madurai";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_MAIN ="hotel";
private static final String TAG_VALUE = "Madurai";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "category";
private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_BANNER = "banner";
private static final String TAG_LOGO = "logo";
private static final String TAG_ABOUT = "about";
private static final String TAG_CONTACT = "contact";
private static final String TAG_MAP = "map";

private static final String TAG_MAP_LAT_LONG = "lat_long_1";
private static final String TAG_MAPLATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String TAG_MAPLONGITUDE = "longitude";
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY_TOTAL = "total";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    Log.v("exact string value", json.toString());
    try {

        // Getting Array of Contacts
        JSONObject js= json.getJSONObject(TAG_MAIN);
        int ival = js.getInt(TAG_CATEGORY_TOTAL);
        contacts = js.getJSONArray(TAG_VALUE);
        Log.v("Total:", ""+ival);
        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String category = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORY);
            String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String banner = c.getString(TAG_BANNER);
            String logo = c.getString(TAG_LOGO);
            String about = c.getString(TAG_ABOUT);
            String contact = c.getString(TAG_CONTACT);

            Log.v("Values:", id+"--"+category+"--"+type+"--"+name+"--"+banner+"--"+logo+"--"+about+"--"+contact);


            // Phone number is agin JSON Object
            JSONObject mapval = c.getJSONObject(TAG_MAP);

            JSONArray con = js.getJSONArray(TAG_VALUE);
            JSONObject mapvalues = con.getJSONObject(0);
            String latitude = mapvalues.getString(TAG_MAPLATITUDE);
            String longitude = mapvalues.getString(TAG_MAPLONGITUDE);
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_CATEGORY, category);
            map.put(TAG_TYPE, type);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            /*Log.v("Received json values", ""+map.toString());*/
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

values i'm getting by running this is exact json

```
01-02 12:03:38.300: V/exact string value(30124): {"hotel":{"total":1,"Madurai":[{"id":"3","logo":"www.glossymob.com\/soli\/MapMadurai\/3_logo_laptop-computer.jpg","category":"Hotel","name":"araas","map":{"lat_long_1":{"longitude":"76.9000","latitude":"8.5000"}},"about":"test","type":"Silver","contact":"test","banner":"www.glossymob.com\/soli\/MapMadurai\/3_banner_laptop-computer.jpg"}]}}
01-02 12:03:38.300: V/Total:(30124): 1
01-02 12:03:38.300: V/Values:(30124): 3--Hotel--Silver--araas--www.glossymob.com/soli/MapMadurai/3_banner_laptop-computer.jpg--www.glossymob.com/soli/MapMadurai/3_logo_laptop-computer.jpg--test--test
```

> When I try to replace this 
>   Main URL

```
(http://www.glossymob.asia/Webservice.asmx/SpecificCategory?category=real%20estate&location=Madurai)
```

> Values I'm getting is

```
01-02 11:07:27.116: V/json string value(29330): <html>
<head> 
   <title>Runtime Error</title>    
<style>         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}          p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}         .version {color: gray;}         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }  
  </style>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="white">    
    <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>            <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>  
      <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">            <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.            <br><br> 
       <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>      
  <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">               <tr>                  <td>                      <code><pre>&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;&lt;configuration&gt;    &lt;system.web&gt;        &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;    &lt;/system.web&gt;&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>                  </td>               </tr>            </table>   
     <br>            <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application's &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br>          
<table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">               <tr>                  <td>                      <code><pre>&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;&lt;configuration&gt;    &lt;system.web&gt;        &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt;    &lt;/system.web&gt;&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>                  </td>               </tr>      
  </table>            <br>  
</body>
</html>
```

> i'm handling that Xml data By replacing that in string and my json returns the exact json string values. Look at my JSONParser class.
>       package com.androidhive.jsonparsingtest;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {


            line = line.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>","");
            line = line.replace("<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">","");
            line = line.replace("</string>","");
            Log.v("string value", line);
            sb.append(line);
            //Log.v("sbstring value", sb.toString());
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.v("json string value", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Comment: It is XML wrapping JSON.

Comment: ya i have handled by replacing those unwanted strings in my json parser. Have a look at my json parser.@nhahtdh

Comment: wi are you using those xml tagged strings in this json. if you neglect that you can get the data.

Answer (score 0):

your response is :-

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{"real estate":{"Madurai":[{"id":"5","category":"real estate","type":"Silver","name":"Heera","banner":"www.glossymob.com/soli/MapMadurai/5_banner_laptop-computer.jpg","logo":"www.glossymob.com/soli/MapMadurai/5_logo_laptop-computer.jpg","about":"test","contact":"test","map":{"lat_long_1":{"latitude":"10.00","longitude":"9.50"}}} ],"total":1} }
</string>
```

Now first you need to replace with

```
responseString = responseString.replace("<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">","");
responseString = responseString.replace("</string>","");
```

please convert the string to JSONObject after replacing above lines.

Comment: i've did that @V.J. my problem is different from that!

Answer (score 0):

It is not pure JSON. It has XML tags in it. Either use XML only, or JSON.

It would be easy if you just remove the XML tags on the top and the bottom, and go ahead with the JSON parsing.

Comment: ya I've done that only dude but I'm able to Replace the strings and fetch exact json when i'm using temp URL. when i try to use my Host URL i'm getting like Html stuffs. @nithinreddy

Comment: I'm sure the problem is not that. You might be using the wrong URL in the code. Because the log you showed is from Server, not from Android.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting JSON response inside `<string>` i.e. XML, so first you have to retrieve JSON data from that tag.

> {"real
>   estate":{"Madurai":[{"id":"5","category":"real
>   estate","type":"Silver","name":"Heera","banner":"www.glossymob.com/soli/MapMadurai/5_banner_laptop-computer.jpg","logo":"www.glossymob.com/soli/MapMadurai/5_logo_laptop-computer.jpg","about":"test","contact":"test","map":{"lat_long_1":{"latitude":"10.00","longitude":"9.50"}}}
>   ],"total":1} }

### Solution:

Call `parse()` once you received the data from web.

For example:

```
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
JSONArray jsonRes = parser.parse(response.getEntity().getContent());
// response is the HTTPResponse object
```

Here is the XMLParser class:

```
public class XMLParser extends DefaultHandler {

    private static String ROOT_ELEMENT = "string";
    private StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();

    private JSONArray jsonData;

    public XMLParser() {
    }

    public JSONArray parse(InputStream in) {
        try {
            SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(in, this);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return jsonData;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        data.replace(0, data.length(), "");

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ROOT_ELEMENT)) {
            jsonData = new JSONArray();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        data.append(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ROOT_ELEMENT)){
            try {
                jsonData = new JSONArray(data.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting json String succesfully. my problem is when i try to use my Main Host URL i'm not getting json.@Paresh Mayani